# Как отправить SMS в фоновом режиме? (API Min равно 22)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Нужно чтобы программа работала в фоновом режиме и с определенным интервалом отправляла смс сообщения.
Вот код службы

```
public class PlayService extends Service {
    private final static int SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQ=1;

    @Nullable
    @Override

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Служба создана",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS))
        {
            SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("*********",null,"sms",null,null);
        }

    }

    private boolean checkPermission(String sendSms) {

        int checkpermission= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,sendSms);
        return checkpermission== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }


    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQ:
                if(grantResults.length>0 &&(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
                {

                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Служба запущена",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS))
        {
            SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("",null,"sms",null,null);
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Служба остановлена",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static int SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQ=1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("SwipeRefreshLayout");
        final Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);
        final Button btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stop);

        // запуск службы
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // используем явный вызов службы
                startService(
                        new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayService.class));
            }
        });

        // остановка службы
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopService(
                        new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayService.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean checkPermission(String sendSms) {

        int checkpermission= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,sendSms);
        return checkpermission== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQ:
                if(grantResults.length>0 &&(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
                {

                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Но смс не отправляет в чем ошибка?

Comment: Разрешение в манифесте есть?

Comment: Конечно есть разрешение

Comment: с api 19 и выше, чтобы приложение могло работать с смс, оно должно быть назначено пользователем смс-клиентом по умолчанию, это сделано в целях безопасности, чтобы недобросовестные программисты не могли отсылать фоновые смс на всякие платные короткие номера без ведома пользователя